# Using Action Helper to pass data to View without controller

Tags: ember.js

I'm trying to translate my emblem.js template code to handlebar (forgive me if I did any mistakes).

My Handlebar code (originally in Emblem.js):

```
{{View CouponTypeView}}
  li.dropdown.sales {{action "select" target="view" menuTab="sales"}}
  li.dropdown.discount {{action "select" target="view" menuTab="discount"}}
```

My View:

```
App.CouponTypeView = Ember.View.extend({                          
  eventManager: Ember.Object.create({
    click: function(event, view, menuTab) {
    console.log(menuTab); // undefined T__T
  })
});
```

I'm trying to get action helper to pass data back to my view but unfortunately it doesn't seem to work.

Thanks!

What I'm trying to do is a list of dropdown box. Only one item in the list can have a dropdown at a time.

I've reread the ember's document and it seems that it passingly state that if I need to keep track of state then use a controller (http://emberjs.com/guides/views/handling-events/) Under Sending Events section.

Answer (score 0):

`{{action "select"}}` will send a `select` event, but you have a `click` handler. You probably want a `select` handler. Beyond that I don't really know Emblem.

Answer (score 0):

If this were the template for the CouponTypeView you would need a select method on the view to have your action helper work:

```
App.CouponTypeView = Ember.View.extend({                          
  select:function(){//do something fun
     }
});
```

However, you're referencing the CouponTypeView in your template, so I'm assuming we are either not in the CouponTypeView's template or there is a nested CouponTypeView.